# Is $(a-x)f''(x)$ decreasing for $f$ convex?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, monotone-functions

Suppose $f: \mathbb R \longrightarrow \mathbb R$ is strictly convex and twice differentiable. Fix $a \in [0,1]$ and let $$g(x) = (a-x)f''(x).$$ Can we say anything about monotonicity properties of $g$ over the unit interval? In particular, is $g$ monotonically decreasing over $[0,1]$?

Comment: Of course not. The only thing you know is that $f''$ is nonnegative, but it can have any prescribed behavior.

Comment: Try $f''(x) = (x-2)^2, a=0$. Note that $g(0)=g(2)=0$ and $g(x)<0$ for $x \in (0,2)$.